# HTML frame tag not supporting style="overflow: xyz"?

Tags: css, inline, frameset, html4

It seems that the HTML `<frame>` tag does not support [overflow styles](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_overflow.asp) like for example `style="overflow: hidden"`.

```
<frame name="menu" src="menu.html" style="overflow: hidden">
```

No matter what I put into the overflow style, it always shows the default behavior (scrollbar).  Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: have you tried to add width and height?

Comment: The `<frame>` element's been deprecated since long ago, so you're doing something wrong, sure. But you could try adding attribute `scrolling="no"`.

Comment: Thanks -- does the `<frame>` element support inline CSS styles at all, or only inline HTML styles?